# cmd picks vim's temporary files instead of script

Tags: windows, vim, cmd

I am trying to use windows for Competitive Programming [new to windows], but cmd keeps picking the vim temporary files instead of my script files

For example, a folder for me looks like

```
.test.py.un~
test.py
test.py~
```

When I type in just test and press tab for autocomplete, it picks the first option and I have to cycle through to get the right one.

This is really annoying, as in macOS and linux distros, it autcompletes based on the first few chars and would have picked the test.py file in an instant.

Am I doing something wrong, and is there any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: Specifically [this one](https://superuser.com/q/584013/83249).

Comment: oh, thought this was more of a configuration problem rather than a windows cmd problem. thanks @Christian.K for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Christian.K , this seems like a windows-cmd problem, which can be fixed using Clink, which gives bash style autocomplete.